# Elasticsearch CORS issue

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, pgsync

I created one deployed directly from the elastic cloud. I am using PGSync for synchronizing table updates with elasticsearch. Since I don't have elastic deployed on any VM I tried some settings in schema.json like this:

```
[
    {
        "setting": {
            "http":{
                "cors":{
                    "enabled": true,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": ["Authorization", "Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With"],
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT"],
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "allow-headers": ["Authorization", "Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With"],
                    "allow-methods": ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT"],
                    "allow-origin": "*"
                }
            },
            "http.cors.enabled" : true,
            "http.cors.allow-origin": "*",
            "http.cors.allow-methods": ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT"],
            "http.cors.allow-headers": ["Authorization", "Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With"],
            "http.cors.allow-credentials": true
        },
        "nodes": {
            "table": "test",
            "schema": "public"
        }
        // ...
    }
]
```

I am first time using elastic search and I am getting a CORS error on the frontend side. I am directly hitting elastic API from front-end.
Here is the console error I am getting while making AJAX call to elastic API:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url/test_inde/_search?q=*' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```